# How do I prove these biconditional statements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

[image]

I keep getting stuck when I get to (not p or q) and (p or not q) for number 3 and for number 4 I get stuck in relatively the same place.

Edit: I want to prove them with using equivalence laws, not truth tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3, $(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q) \Leftrightarrow\\
((P \land Q) \lor \neg P ) \land ((P\land Q) \lor \neg Q) \Leftrightarrow \\
((P\lor \neg P)\land (Q \lor \neg P)) \land ((P\lor \neg Q)\land (Q\lor \neg Q)) \Leftrightarrow \\
(P\lor \neg P)\land (Q \lor \neg P) \land (P\lor \neg Q)\land (Q\lor \neg Q)\Leftrightarrow\\
(\neg P \lor Q)\land (\neg Q \lor P)\Leftrightarrow\\
(P\rightarrow Q) \land (Q\rightarrow P)\Leftrightarrow\\
(P\leftrightarrow Q)$

Using this in 4 gives, $\neg(P\leftrightarrow Q)\Leftrightarrow\\
\neg((P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)) \Leftrightarrow\\
\neg(P\land Q)\land \neg(\neg P \land \neg Q)\Leftrightarrow\\
(\neg P \lor \neg Q) \land(P\lor Q)\Leftrightarrow\\
(P\rightarrow \neg Q) \land (\neg Q \rightarrow P)\Leftrightarrow\\
(P\leftrightarrow \neg Q)$

Hopefully each of the steps are self explanatory.